# DatePicker is not working

Tags: datetime

Datepicker is not working. This code working with Drupal 6, but not with Drupal 7.

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js', 'module');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/jquery.min.js', 'module');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js', 'module');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/datepicker.js', 'module');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/ztfb_datepicker.js', 'module');
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/ui.all.css', 'module');

drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'PROPERTY') .'/jquery/scrollJump.js', 'module');
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
  $("#startdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat:'dd-mm-yy',
    autosize:false,
    changeYear:true,
    changeMonth:true       
  });
});
```

I include the file in PROPERTY_Form.admin.inc file.

```
require_once("D://wamp/www/propertysite/cron/includes/jquerydatepicker.php");

function PROPERTY_Form() {
  global $user; 
  $form = array();

  $form['PROPERTY_Form']['startSyncFrom'] = array(      
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#prefix'=>'<tr><td>',
    '#suffix'=>'</td></tr>',
    '#id'=>'startdate',
    '#default_value'=>date('d-m-Y'),
    '#description' => '(You can select any past date to ensure even your old Data gets synced)',
    '#attributes'=>array('tabindex'=>9,'style'=>'width:70px;'),
  ); 

  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to include all of that jquery libraries: Drupal core has that libraries. You can just include any jquery.ui library with `drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.datepicker')` or another library which you want to include. Then, in your JavaScript file, you can write something like this.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custom_js = {
    attach: function(context) {
      $('#YOURID input[type="text"]').datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: Drupal.settings.basePath + "sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/images/calendar.png",
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        showAnim: "slideDown",
        buttonImageOnly: true
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

If you want to use the datepicker with the form API, you have to change the type element to 'date_popup'.

Comment: drupal_add_library('system','ui.datepicker');
drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy", 
      autoSize: true
    });});', 'inline'); while puting in  PROPERTY_Form.admin.inc file its works

Comment: This is working fine for me thanks. With out Drupal behaviors, I have added it in my custom js. Icon disabled when there is error in form. With behaviors its working cool.